# Show that the following function is bounded by $\frac{d}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that $\forall x \ge 2$, the function $f$ defined by (note that $0 < d < 1$, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$)
$$f(x) = \frac{x \sin \left( \frac{\pi d}{x} \right) \sin \left( \frac{2 \pi n}{x} \right)}{2 \pi n \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{x} \right)}$$
satisfies $|f(x)| < \frac{d}{2}$.

Note: This is NOT homework

So far:

If we set $y = \frac{\pi}{x}$, then we need to show that the absolute value of
$$\frac{\sin(yd) \sin(2ny)}{2yn \sin(y)}$$ is less than $\frac{d}{2}$ for all $y \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$. Using Jordan's inequality, we have:

$$\frac{\sin(yd) \sin(2ny)}{2ny \sin(y)} \leq \frac{\pi \sin(dy) \sin(2ny)}{4ny^2}$$

Another application of Jordan's inequality reveals that

$$\frac{\pi \sin(dy) \sin(2ny)}{4ny^2} \leq \frac{\pi d \sin(2ny)}{4ny}$$

Comment: Welcome to [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com)! For questions of this sort, it is customary to also mention what you know about the problem, what work you have put into the problem, as well as what your thoughts are toward the overall solution. That way, we can deliver the correct level of help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use [Jordan's inequality](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_inequality).

Comment: I still can't seem to get the answer. I've included my work in the main post.